# Trying to insert a mix of non-static variables and retrieved values into a table

Tags: sql, db2

So I'm trying to insert a collection of non-static variables and values fetched from another table into a table using a subquery. My code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TAB_REQ(TABLE_I, RUN_I, CODE, ORG_ALS, TAB_CRT_S, TAB_LST_UPD_S)
SELECT :tableKey, :runKey, :code, :org, TAB.CRT_S, TAB.LST_UPD_S
FROM   SCHEMA.TABLE TAB
WHERE  TAB.KEY = :tableKey
```

The values being fetched, TAB.CRT_S and TAB.LST_UPD_S, are both going to be timestamps. So "12/3/2019 12:00:01 AM" as an example. Neither of these values should ever be null. They're automatically generated whenever a new row is inserted.

The provided variables are going to be two strings of integers (:tableKey and :runKey) and then two strings (:code and :org). They're provided by a java application, and if they're missing then something has gone terribly wrong. Right now I'm manually entering values for each variable when I run the query.

The select statement should only return a single row, because :tableKey is an automatically generated unique identifier.

My current code is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR [42610] [IBM][DB2] SQL0418N  The statement was not processed because the statement contains an invalid use of one of the following: an untyped parameter marker, the DEFAULT keyword, or a null value.
```

Is this possible, or do I need two seperate queries here?

Comment: What is your question?  Does this code work?  If not, what is the problem?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: An example of the data being grabbed here and inserted would be useful.  Are there any null values in the fields being "selected"?

Comment: Are the added details the sort of example you were looking for?

Comment: Show the part of your java code, where you work with the corresponding PreparedStatement / DB2PreparedStatement variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a much simpler way to do what I needed. Instead of trying to gather all the data that I needed in a single query, I wrote two simple select statements and used them to insert the extra parameters into my java variable before it populated the variables in this SQL statement.